# Elasticsearch simple query string: removing documents containing words

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a foo example to express what I mean. Suppose we have an index which documents contain the words Text and Texture.

Then I'd like to select all documents containing the word Text (I'm using the simple query string).

When I use the query "query": "Text", I get areas 1, 2 and 3 from the picture bellow.

When I use the query "query": "Text -Texture", I get only the area 3 from the picture bellow.

How could I get both areas 2 and 3?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you're getting area 1 when querying for text, it means you either have indexed prefixes (using edge-ngrams or ngrams) or you're using a wildcard in your query.

Answer (score 0):

To understand your problem you need to post your query.
Try to use `term`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "myField": "Text"
        }
    }
}
```